# Create / open a .ssmssln or .ssmssqlproj in Visual Studio Data Tools (2017)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssms-2017

Any way to add a template to Visual Studio 2017 to 
Create a .ssmssln or .ssmssqlproj that can also be opened in SSMS 2017?

Comment: SSMS 2017 and Visual Studio are completely different tools. What are you actually truing to achieve here..?

Comment: The SSMS projects are rather lame and limited. If you really wanted to, yes, you can have these things created outside SSMS, because they're secretly just VS solution/project files, albeit ones opened only with the SSMS VS shell (standalone VS won't open them directly). One's a simple text file and the other's XML. The big question would be why you'd want to -- it's really only good for shipping a bunch of connection strings and scripts, and that doesn't really require a solution.

Comment: What we would be trying to accomplish is to be able to use TFS to store and version control .sql files or scripts.  Cannot connect or use team explorer thru the SSMS client.  VS database project where you can create and store .sql files is not as popular with our developers.

Comment: i am looking for this as well. I have many stored queries on SSMS saved in ssmssln project. i want to sync into Azure git repos. SSMS do not have GIT and i am trying to load in VS and sync GIt.